# Which of these are association relationships?

Tags: c++, software-design

I have been studying about object relationships and I want to clear up any misunderstandings if I have any.

Here is some code:

```
class object 
{
    int data;

public:

    object(int d): data(d)
    {
    }

    int get_data() 
    { 
        return data;  
    }

    int set_data(int d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

};


class A
{
    object* o;

public:

    A(object& test) : o(&test) 
    {
    }

};


class B
{


public:
    B()
    {
        object o(10);
        o.set_data(100);
    }
};



class C
{
public:
    C(object& o)
    {
        o.set_data(100);
    }
};
```

Which classes have an association relationship with the class "object"??

I believe A is aggregation
I am not sure about B, but if I had to guess, I believe it would be association
I believe C is association

I am not 100% sure about my answers.

Is there considered to be a relationship between objects if an object is created in and used in another objects function?  Example: class B.

Comment: You need to read up on the concepts.  All three of your answers are incorrect.

Comment: Could you clarify how all three answers are incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

A nice tip to remember is that composition bounds the lifetime of objects (Laptop > Screen), aggregations simply state there is a parent/child relationship but they can exist independently (Laptop > Mouse) while for association there is no relation at all they just connect at some point (Laptop - User).

So here yes if you create an object A you tie the "object" parameter in it and when you destroy A you also destroy the inner object so it's an aggregation.

In class B & C you do not set any object so there is no association at all, just a dependency for the class C and maybe the class B but that's really open to interpretation I believe.

Comment: Could you give me some clarification on class A's relationship to class "object"? I thought that because object A's data member was a pointer, it would not be composition because the object "test" passed to the constructor can exist even when object A is destroyed.

Comment: Yes you're right it's only an aggregation but the pointer has nothing to do with it, it would be a composition if the object was created inside the constructor and destroyed in the same destructor.